# How to remove label in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

now i am trying to use custom toolbar i created, but there is a label with white color. 
[text : test with white color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHuRu.png)

how can i remove this?

below are my manifest and styles.xml code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- No Title Bar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

update my toolbar.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="resquare_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

Comment: Try posting your custom toolbar xml?

Comment: How about `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`?

Comment: @WilsonSim i had update my toolbar xml

Comment: @dotGitignore umm...if i changed into kotlin, i got error "only safe(?.) or non null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Actionbar?"

Comment: @dotGitignore thx by fixing code like val ab= supportActionBar if(ab!=null)ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin you can do as

```
 val toolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
 supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarActionBar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            (this).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

or:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

or this to hide

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. I am not getting any kind of white label

> Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".TestActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

> style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

> ```
> activity_test.xml
> ```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="resquare_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

> ```
> TestActivity.java
> ```

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }
```